# Stateful SMS Gateway Utility

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, stateful

I have installed **Kannel** as my SMS gateway service on my Server.
And it's running at a long time ago.
Basically, the default sms long text is 140 chars.
And i want to make it two step sending message, i mean i can send text message twice and sms gateway hold my first session (Stateful).
It impossible to replace production with the newest technology.

Cause right now, it just stateless. I send message and sms gateway just pass through it.

I think i need third party engine that can hold and manage sms sending session.
But i don't know, what that engine is. Cause it send as SMS message.

Any idea?
Thank you very much :)